# Probability question: An insurance company looks at its auto insurance customers and finds that (a) all insure at least one car,

Tags: probability

An insurance company looks at its auto insurance customers and finds that 
(a) all insure at least one car, 
(b) 85% insure more than one car, 
(c) 23% insure a sport car, 
(d) 17% insure more than one car, including a sport car. 
Find the probability that a customer selected at random insures exactly one car and it is not a sport car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using (c) and (d), we have that 23% - 17% = 6% of people insure exactly one car, which is a sports car.

Using (a) and (b), we see that 15% insure exactly one car.

Then, combining these results, we find that 15% - 6% = 9% insure only one car, which is not a sports car.